# On not wasting data when taking lags of one variable

Tags: dataset, lags, data-preprocessing

I just have a basic question about what 'best practice' generally is, in such a situation:

Suppose I have two finite time series of equal length $\{x(t)\}_{t \in I}$ and $\{y(t)\}_{t \in I}$ and say I want to regress $(x(t)-x(t-i))$ against $y(t)$, where $i$ is a fixed constant positive integer.

This results in a bunch of unused data points, namely, the first $i$ data points, since there are no further values back in the $x$ time series to take differences of.

Similarly, if we take differences with greater lags, we will see more unused data points. In such cases, what is generally a good way to make use of that data without totally wasting it?

Backfilling the last difference, i.e. using constant $x(i+1)- x(1)$ for the first $i$ entries? Or using $x(j) - \mu$ for $j \le i$, where $\mu$ is some local average of the $x$ values? Or what?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Inventing data, or using the wrong differences in place of the correct ones, cannot be of any help--and will likely create erroneous results.  When you don't have data, you simply don't have data: you haven't "wasted" anything.